# What happens when we declare Array(4) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
console.log(Array(4).join("hi"));
>> "hihihi"
```

I don't get what exactly is happening here?

Comment: `Array(4)` creates array of 4 `undefined` elements. `join` will join the array using the `hi` as _glue_ and thus giving **3** `hi` ignoring `undefined`s.

Comment: @Tushar, But `undefined` are ignored..

Comment: @RayonDabre - undefined elements are still used in a `.join()`: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/jcf5xkak/

Comment: @jfriend00, Could not see them in log...

Comment: @RayonDabre  - the output is not in the console, it's right in the output window of the jsFiddle.

Comment: @jfriend00, yes, I was expecting `"undefined"` in the output as it works with `0/true/false` as I did not know `join` excludes `null/undefined`

Answer (score 1):

`join()` is the opposite of `split()`. whereas split separates an array by the delimiting character you pass it, join will instead combine all the elements delimiting each one with whatever parameter you pass.

In this case the array is simply `Array(4)`, so 4 undefined elements. combining these will yield "`undefined`hi`undefined`hi`undefined`hi`undefined`".

Since js doesn't [actually treat undefined as anything](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) in this case, it turns it into an empty string and all you get is `hihihi`

edit: reference for my last statement from the `join()` documentation:

> The string conversions of all array elements are joined into one string. If an element is undefined or null, it is converted to the empty string.

Comment: _Since js doesn't actually treat undefined as anything_ Any reference to defend this statement ?

Comment: edited to reflect answer to your comment

Comment: It's not nothing - it's an empty string.

Comment: [`If an element is undefined or null, it is converted to the empty string`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join#Description)

Comment: @Pabs123, Great! Thank you :)